# Can I use this high-side driver with arduino?

Tags: arduino, current, driver, 12v

I have salvaged a PCB with quite few single and multi-channel high side drivers. One of the is [VN5E010AH](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00240716.pdf). If I understood datasheet, this chip can drive high voltage using low voltage cmos compatible input. The reason I am interested in using this chip is analog current sense (5V max out).

Would this work with arduino, and what is cmos compatible input?

Answer (score 4):

From the datasheet:

> V<sub>IL</sub>: 0.9V (max)
>   V<sub>IH</sub>: 2.1V (min)

This means that it will work with an Arduino (or any other CMOS digital device) with a supply of 3V.

A "CMOS-compatible input" is one that considers any voltage 0.3 or lower times the supply voltage to be a 0, and any voltage 0.7 or higher times the supply voltage to be a 1. Since the device specifies "3V CMOS", this means that the maximum low input voltage must be at least 0.9V, and the minimum high input voltage must be no higher than 2.1V. The values in the datasheet match these exactly.

Note that for a CMOS-compatible output, the factors are 0.1 and about 0.9 instead; this device could be used with any CMOS device with a supply between 2.1V/0.9=2.33V and 0.9V/0.1=9V inclusive, provided the output has sufficient drive (see I<sub>IL</sub> and I<sub>IH</sub> on the datasheet) and that the absolute maximums of the driver are not exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

"CMOS compatible input" means an input compatible with CMOS outputs, and in this case VIL 0.9V and VIH 2.1V is compatible with CMOS outputs of typical MCUs at both 3V and 5V.  For example AVR outputs:

> VOL for 5V supply: < 0.9V;   for 3V supply: < 0.6V
>
> VOH for 5V supply: > 4.2;    for 3V supply: > 2.3

That explains the 'easy 3V and 5V compatible interface" remark.

To be clear, I'm saying the "series R" proposed by Joe is not needed, and approving Ignacio's revised answer that this driver will indeed work with 5V CMOS outputs. Of course, providing current requirements are met, which will indeed be the case if this device is the only load.